# How can I go about creating a scrollable page content using arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm just experimenting around with HTML and JavaScript and I'm a bit stumped on how I can do this.

I want to create a page that can be scrolled using arrow keys on the keyboard or pressing a button to scroll to the next page.

The idea is to have the content spread out but by using the arrow keys it'll go to the next piece of content without reloading the web page. I've tried a few things including AngularJS but I'd rather have it hardcoded and not using a framework (unless it's extremely difficult without)

[image: paint example]

So you can see that there'd be an arrow button/arrow key pressed which would trigger the next page. Could this be done in multiple HTML files or would it be better doing it all in one file and having each page of content in different divs?

Once I'd figured that out I'd be looking to implement an animation so that when the arrow is pressed you can see the next page overlap the previous one.

Comment: _to scroll to the next page_ so... to the next page or to the next section?

Comment: Can be done using javascript to move the page either scrolling or moving with CSS, for right arrow use keycode 39 and left arrow is 37.

Comment: @Smollet777 Scroll to the next page's content, but load it without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```js
var selected = 2;

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') {
    right();
  } else if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    left();
  }
}

function left() {
  var section1 = document.getElementById('1');
  var section2 = document.getElementById('2');
  var section3 = document.getElementById('3');
  
  if (selected == 2) {
    section1.style.left = '0vw';
    section2.style.left = '100vw';
    section3.style.left = '200vw';
    
    selected = 1;
  } else if (selected == 3) {
    section1.style.left = '-100vw';
    section2.style.left = '0vw';
    section3.style.left = '100vw';
    
    selected = 2;
  }
}

function right() {
  var section1 = document.getElementById('1');
  var section2 = document.getElementById('2');
  var section3 = document.getElementById('3');
  
  if (selected == 1) {
    section1.style.left = '-100vw';
    section2.style.left = '0vw';
    section3.style.left = '100vw';
    
    selected = 2;
  } else if (selected == 2) {
    section1.style.left = '-200vw';
    section2.style.left = '-100vw';
    section3.style.left = '0vw';
    
    selected = 3;
  }
}
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  width: calc(100vw - 32px);
  height: 10vh;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.scrollale {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(90vh - 32px); /* For the padding of the header */
  overflow: hidden; /* Remove the scroll bar from the bottom */
}

.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  font-size: 48px;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

.scroll:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
}

.left {
  left: 16px;
}

.right {
  right: 16px;
}

.section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(90vh - 32px); /* For the padding of the header*/
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.part1 {
  left: -100vw;
}

.part2 {
  left: 0vw;
}

.part3 {
  left: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="scroll left" onclick="left()"><</div>
  <div id="1" class="section part1">Section 1</div>
  <div id="2" class="section part2">Section 2</div>
  <div id="3" class="section part3">Section 3</div>
  <div class="scroll right" onclick="right()">></div>
</div>
```

If the arrow keys don't work try clicking the buttons frist (to select it).

### Edit

I the key detection method to use the `key` value which should be more consistent.

Comment: This works pretty well, thanks a lot! I'm guessing it's possible to load HTML pages into those div's using jQuery?

Comment: @Red Thanks!, I've never used jQuery so I wouldn't know, sorry

Comment: hey man, the code is working great when the buttons are pressed but it just won't work with the arrow keys. I'm really awful with javascript and can't figure out what's wrong with it

Comment: In the snippent or in your site?

Comment: on the snippet and my site!

Comment: Sorry could you try it now?